# Using a single page to display information from multiple pages

Tags: 2013, list, navigation, hyperlink

I would like to display information regarding multiple projects using only one .aspx page.

Is it possible to display custom web parts which are defined by a link from a previous page, rather than creating a whole new page and adding the web parts you require?

I imagine this to be similar to php functionality of slotting in lines of code from an external source.

Comment: what version of SP?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Comment: your request is a bit unclear, where will the "information" on each project live (in a list, in sub-sites, all across your entire farm)?  you want to be able to "pick" a particular project and view the details about that project?

you could use Content Search Web Part to roll up details, content query web part, or just a local list with filters and sorting.

Comment: Apologies, let me give a more clear example.

I have a project page which will display 5 projects, i want each of the projects to  link to a specific page with information about those projects, including text, images and web parts. However, i do not want to create a separate page for each of the projects (and future projects) as this will result in clutter and many many pages to manage. Ideally i would like them to link to one page, where i can customize the information shown to the project which has been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post might answer your question (if I interpret it correctly):

[Query String URLs are Magical (Part 2 of 4)](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=70&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0)

It uses Query Strings in the URL to pass in the project ID as a parameter to another page and uses the query string filter web part to parse that parameter out of the URL.

I think this is what you mean by "defined by a link from a previous page".